# How do Query File Field That is related foreign key

Tags: python, django, models

Hello guys am stuck trying all i can to query file in a foreignkey but it doesn't work django throws up an error i have been trying to do this for long now I just gave and now i am back to it need help!

```
    from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models


class Examination(models.Model):
    examination_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True)

    class Meta:
        verbose_name='examination'
        verbose_name_plural='examinations' 

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.examination_name

class YearAndExaminationName(models.Model):
    exam_name = models.ForeignKey(Examination)
    examination_year = models.CharField(max_length=4)


    class Meta:
        verbose_name='year and examination name'
        verbose_name_plural='year and examination names'

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.examination_year


class PastQuestion(models.Model):
    year_and_exam_name = models.ForeignKey(YearAndExaminationName)
    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='self')
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='uploads/', max_length=100,)
    posted_by = models.CharField(max_length=40)


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.file_name
```

What i intended doing is to get pdf to display files by referencing from view via id or pk but when i search stackoverflow or google what I get is how to convert html to pdf.

my views

```
def jamb_detail(request):
    instance = get_object_or_404()
    context = {
    "title":"Jamb Past Question",
    "instance":instance.year_and_exam_name,
    }
    return render(request, 'past_question/jamb_detail.html', context)
```

Comment: include your views.py

Comment: I don't have any idea how to go about rendering the pdf. since am uploading from django admin.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In **views.py**

```
def pdf_view(request):

    # get file path by querying model and then
    with open('/path/to/my/file.pdf', 'rb') as pdf:
        response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), mimetype='application/pdf')
        response['Content-Disposition'] = 'inline;filename=some_file.pdf'
        return response
    pdf.closed
```

Comment: do I have to specify the file I want to display? because I am not planning on displaying just one pdf file as shown here I am uploading a lot of file from my model I want to display the file name then I will get the pdf rendered in the browser.    file_name = models.CharField(max_length=40, default='self') then i will display the pdf file.

Comment: Yes you need to specify the file.

Comment: but i will be querying a lot files. like getting a post by id=id......?  am kind of confused here.

Comment: You can create a dynamic path and use dynamic file name.

Comment: Instead of `/path/to/my/file.pdf` you can use `'/path/' + dynamicfilename` and then pass that.

Comment: I will try what u have given me and get back with whatever result i have.

Comment: @user6771817, If the solution worked for you, please select the answer. Thanks for all the cooperation.